# Absolutely positioned anchor tag inside relatively positioned li not working

Tags: css

I am trying to create a menu as follows. When hover the menu item, it should be animate the height from bottom to top. So I positioned anchor tag absolute and gave bottom 0. When anchor tag is positioned absolute, It does not show menu properly.

```
css is as follows.
    #navigation
{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin-top:55px;
    padding-right:45px;
}

#navigation ul
{
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#navigation ul li a
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    padding:10px 5px;
    width:79px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#1c1c1c;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    /*margin:2px;
    margin-bottom:0px;*/
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    /*position:relative;*/
    font-size:15px;

}
```

html is as follows.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/90up4hz2/

Comment: Create a [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Comment: Look at my answer here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L0r493ag/3/ it will help you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/90up4hz2/1/

the issue is because of `position:absolute` for the li and `position:relative` the width becomes `0` try adding fixed with for `li`

```
#navigation ul li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:30px;
    width:89px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/L0r493ag/2/

I created this for you, dont use ul li or just add the follow css to them or to any object

```
.boxhead 
{    
color: #afaeae;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
background:#000000;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    height:50px;
}

.boxhead:hover 
{
color: #7d7d7d;
}
```

and then

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a class="boxhead" href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a class="boxhead" href="about-us.php">About Us</a>
        <a class="boxhead" href="products.php">Products</a>
        <a class="boxhead" href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a>

</div>
```